# Regex to check for a number in the url using Twig

Tags: php, regex, symfony, twig

This wouldnt be a big problem if I had known Twig a little more.
Here is my code, I am trying to check whether the url contains number in it.

```
{% set x = req.path %}
{% set matches = x|regex_match('~[\d\.]+$~') %}

{% set matches = x|regex_match('~[0-9]*$+~') %}
```

none of these work

thanks in advance

Comment: Then why do you anchor the pattern? Try `'~[0-9]~'`.

Comment: I did try this pattern too... no luck there :(

Comment: Try `{% if x matches '{^\D*\d[\s\S]*$}' %}
    Do Stuff
{% endif %}` or `{% if x matches '/\\d/' %}
        Do Stuff
    {% endif %}`

Comment: its not working for me...

Comment: {% if x matches '/\\d/' %} Do Stuff {% endif %} worked. I am so glad. thanks a ton. :) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Twig reference](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons):

> For complex string comparisons, the `matches` operator allows you to use regular expressions:
>
> `{% if phone matches '/^[\\d\\.]+$/' %}`
> `{% endif %}`

So, to check if a string contains a digit with a regex, just use

```
{% if x matches '/\\d/' %}
    Do Stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why do you backslash escape the `\d`? I can see that it's necessary, but not documented anywhere?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis The reason is that two backslashes are used in a single-quoted string literal in PHP to define a literal backslash. Unknow string escape sequences are resolved to combinations of a backslash + the escaped char, so in most cases it is safe to use a single backslash, so `'/\d/'` or `'/^[\d.]+$/'` will work, too. **Note** the dot does not have to be escaped inside a character class, I was rather green 6 years ago and thought it safer to have it escaped, but it is really not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Why using Twig for this ? should be more reliable to use the routing functionnalities ?

```
my_route_to_check:
pattern:  /my/route/{id}
defaults: { _controller: acmeMybundle:myController:myAction, id:0}
requirements:
     id : \d+
```

here {id} has to be a integer ( with \d+ rules ) otherwise an exception will be triggered.

easier , no ?

Comment: I use a tool for my development, it works on Twig. Doesnt work with other stuff...

Comment: could you please give us information on your tools ? i m curious